# Eclipse Code Formatter indents with double amount of spaces - Intellij IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, code-formatting

I have configured Eclipse Code Formatter to indent with 4 spaces but after run code formatter I'm getting double amount of spaces.

[image]

When I indent with standard settings of Intellij I'm getting correct amount of spaces.

Checkstyle rule:

```
<module name="Indentation">
    <property name="basicOffset" value="4"/>
    <property name="braceAdjustment" value="0"/>
    <property name="caseIndent" value="4"/>
    <property name="throwsIndent" value="4"/>
    <property name="lineWrappingIndentation" value="4"/>
    <property name="arrayInitIndent" value="4"/>
</module>
```

Eclipse Code Formatter:

```
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.tabulation.char" value="space"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.tabulation.size" value="4"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.indentation.size" value="4"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.continuation_indentation" value="4"/>
```

Settings of IDE:
[image]

What can cause double size of indentation after run the code formatter?

Comment: Remove IntelliJ from the title and tag if this question is about Eclipse.

Comment: this question is about using Eclipse Code Formatter in Intellij IDE

Comment: Why would you do that?  IntelliJ can format code just fine without it.

Comment: Because in our team we have some developers which use Intellij and others which use Eclipse. We need code formatter which can be used in both IDEs. Problem is that this settings of Eclipse Code Formatter are not changing indentation to 4 spaces but to 8. This error is also detected by checkstyle.

Comment: Sorry, if I were on your team I'd use IntelliJ properly and ignore the rest.

Comment: Too make it even more weird. Intellij IDE displays this 8 spaces as 4 (line 16 - 4 spaces, line 18 - 8 spaces).

Comment: The latest version of IntelliJ does no such thing for me.  I'd revert back to standard code style, remove that formatter, and try again.

Comment: What an ignorant response. If the team requires identical code style, then the plugin is the only way.

Comment: @Beacze I don't see any double amount of spaces in your screenshot. Only tabs have variable size in IntelliJ, spaces are just spaces - and there is no double amount of them.

Comment: Message from checkstyle informs about amount of spaces (message in German: Einrückungstiefe von 8 (erwatet 4))

Comment: So is the message wrong or what?

Comment: Formatting looks correct, maybe it's Checkstyle plug-in bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I experienced the same behavior with eclipse code formatter for "continuation indents", the amount of spaces was doubled from 4 to 8. My eclipse code formatter file had these lines:

```
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.tabulation.char" value="space"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.tabulation.size" value="4"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.indentation.size" value="4"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.continuation_indentation" value="2"/>
```

The last line with "continuation_indentation" was set to to 2 which led me to the conclusion this could be a factor of 2 (4 x 2 = 8, right ). I changed the value to "1" and it worked. Maybe that helps.

Btw. my settings in Intellij look the same like yours [image]